# What's a recursive algorithm for finding the floor of a non-negative real number?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, ceiling-and-floor-functions

The definition of the floor function is clear and all, I just can't think of a recursive definition to find the floor of a non-negative real number.

Comment: Why are you interested in a recursive algorithm? If you have an IEEE floating point number, find its floor can easily be done directly without resorting to recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x)$ = if $x<1$ return $0,$ else return $f(x-1)+1.$

For large $x$ this may be subject to rounding errrors, depending on how numbers are stored/ manipulated.

Answer (score 0):

How about

$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}x, & x\in\mathbb{Z}\\f(x)-\frac1\pi|\sin(\pi f(x))|,&\text{else}\end{cases} $$

Answer (score 0):

This would work, I think:

Define `Floor(real R, integer I)` as follows:

```
integer Floor(real R, integer I) {
    //assumes that R >= 0
    if R <= I
        return I
    else
        return Floor(R, I+1)
}
```

Invoke the algorithm by calculating `Floor(R, 0)`.

For large real numbers, it will take a loooooooong time to calculate it, and lots of stack space on your computer, but it will eventually hit the right integer, without fail.

(There are far better ways to calculate the floor than with a recursive function in practice.)